# Why only “???????” are displayed when Ukrainian text is outputed in pdf generation?

Tags: laravel, pdf-generation

On Laravel 9 site I generate pdf file based on blade.php template which has in its header  :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ua" xml:lang="ua" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Report</title>
</head>
```

In blade file I output content in Ukrainian language from database with code:

```
{{ $Row['user_name'] }}
```

and I generate pdf file
But only “???????” are displayed.

All tables in my db has :

```
   ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

I suppose that is default charset for database I created

```
"barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^2.0",
"laravel/framework": "^9.47",
```

Now in application english, ukrainian and spain are used, but other languages can be added...

How that can be salved ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue: Fellow these steps:
1- Check your Laravel connection in config database config file

```
 'connections' => [
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
```

2- Check your database config in PHPMYADMIN

```
utf8mb4 character set and utf8mb4_unicode_ci collation
```

Comment: 1) Yes, have these parameters
2) File /etc/phpmyadmin/config-db.php or /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php have no such parameters
In which file and in which way  have I add these parameters ?

Comment: when you create Database in PHPMYADMIN chose utf8mb4 character set and utf8mb4_unicode_ci collation.

Comment: Actually both  utf8mb4 character with  utf8mb4_unicode_ci collation are in my database(I show it in first topic)
and in settings of config/database.php (I checked it). I suppose there could ne 2 possible place :
1) In header of blade file, as I have <meta charset="UTF-8"/> now 
2) Make some encoding in output of {{ $Row['user_name'] }} ?
3) Not sure if barryvdh/laravel-dompdf library have some options for that ?